# Validate excel file before uploading using javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, jquery-file-upload

I need to write a functionality to upload an excel file (size: 1 GB). 
I would like to validate the column name of excel file. If that matches the predefined column names then only upload the file else show error.

My question is: Is there a way to validate(need to check only the column name) this huge excel file using javascript or jquery ?

ps: at backend I am using Spring.

Comment: if you are looking for javascript/jquery, why do you tag this as java?

Comment: check this link -  [HTML 5 File API](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-html5-file-api-to-work-with-files-locally-in-the-browser). It works locally in browser on media files. But can be used to open excel files in same way

Comment: For reading xls/xlsx files in JS- 
http://codetheory.in/parse-read-excel-files-xls-xlsx-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

please follow the below concept using this way you will be able to get your required results

const importExcel = (e) => {
const file = e.target.files[0]

```
const reader = new FileReader()
reader.onload = (event) => {
  //parse data

  const bstr = event.target.result
  const workBook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: "binary" })

  //get first sheet
  const workSheetName = workBook.SheetNames[0]
  const workSheet = workBook.Sheets[workSheetName]

  //convert to array
  const fileData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet, { header: 1 })
  // console.log(fileData)
  const headers = fileData[0]
  const heads = headers.map(head => ({ title: head, field: head }))
  setColDefs(heads)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).